# How to check whether a server supports SSL with Java?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I need to check whether a server supports SSL and the ciphers from the web server.

I looked into SSLSocket in Java but I do not get it to work properly.

I used the method `getSupportedProtocols()` it always gives out the same protocols for each url. Moreover I do not get the ciphers that are given from the server. I guessed `getEnabledCipherSuites()` would be the correct method

```java
try {
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getDefault();
    ctx.getClientSessionContext().setSessionTimeout(5); // in seconds
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ctx.getSocketFactory().createSocket("host.com", 443);

    socket.setSoTimeout(5000); // in millis
    String[] result = socket.getEnabledCipherSuites();
    Arrays.sort(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(result[i]); 
    }
 } catch (IOException ex) {
     System.out.println("Error!");
 }
```

How can I check that the server uses SSL? What ciphers were returned from the server?

Comment: I don't think this data is available to you.  The way SSL cipher negotiation seems to work is your client sends the ciphers it supports and the server returns the cipher it wants to use from that list.

Comment: Apache even has a directive, [`SSLHonorCipherOrder`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslhonorcipherorder) which causes it to use the leftmost cipher in the cipher list that the client supports rather than relying on the client's preference.  This is used to mitigate a number of attacks, such as BEAST.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getSupportedProtocols()/CipherSuites()` returns the lists of protocols and ciphers (respectively) that *your side* can support. `getEnabledProtocols()/CipherSuites()` returns the subset of these lists that are enabled on your side.

That won't tell you much about about what the server supports.

According to the TLS specification, the client sends the highest protocol version can use and the list of cipher suites it wants to use. The server then uses the highest protocol it supports within that list (if any) and selects the cipher suite it wants amongst that list (if any).

There's some flexibility regarding how the cipher suite selection is done (see [`SSLHonorCipherOrder` directive in Apache Httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslhonorcipherorder), for example).

Essentially, if you want to see which cipher suites are actually supported by your server, you'll have to iterate through each cipher suite you support and enable them one by one to try a handshake.

Comment: that means i need to retrieve all possible cipher methods, then set one cipher suit with probably setEnabledCipherSuites(String[] suites) and then try a handshake. I guess I have to put at end of the try block socket.startHandshake(); 
and in the catch i can set a boolean value to false when it fails
did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, exactly, if the handshake fail, it's not supported. For debugging purposes, you should probably look at why the handshake failed (since there could be other reasons). Make sure at least one cipher suite works first (so that you know the certificate is trusted, for example).

Comment: Thank you, Bruno. It is great help. I worked my way trough the SSL test. I set SSLv2Hello,SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2. And used a handshake. I am still unsure if my outputs are correct. Namely I thought that the docs.oracle.com does not support SSL but in my program the output is true.

Answer (score 0):

> used the method getSupportedProtocols() it always gives out the same protocols for each url.

It always give you the protocols supported by your end. That doesn't change per URL.

> Moreover I do not get the ciphers that are given from the server. I guessed getEnabledCipherSuites() would be the correct method.

You guessed wrong. It gives you the ciphers supported by your end.

> How can I check that the server uses SSL?

Call `startHandshake()` and catch the exception.

> What ciphers were returned from the server?

You can't, but you can tell what cipher suite was negotiated, by looking in the `SSLSession`.

Comment: I am not sure who down voted this but it sounds very similar to Brunos post.

Comment: @A.Dumas It is indeed. They were posted within a couple of minutes of each other, so we were typing at the same time. The similarity indicates correctness, or else mutual delusion.